# Weierstrass $M$-test problem, $f_n(x)=(nx^2)/(n^3+x^3)$

Tags: real-analysis

> Use the Weierstrass M-test to show $$f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{nx^2}{n^3+x^3}$$ converges uniformly on any finite interval $[-R,R]$.

This was an exam question I had. My attempt was to find an upper bound for $\frac{nx^2}{n^3+x^3}$ by taking the derivative and finding critical points. One issue I had was that the function isn't defined if $x = -n$ for any $n \in \mathbb{N}$. I suppose we could just take the sum to start at $\mathrm{Ceil}(R)$.

My attempts to find critical points for the derivative led me to concluding $f_n'(x)=0$ if $x=0$ or $x$ has
$$-nx^3-n^4x+2n^4=0.$$

The class is over, is there any kind of hints to do this or was I on the right track? Thanks very much

Comment: You are right, this is an issue. And a serious one. This series is not defined (not even talking about convergence) on $-\mathbb{N}^*$. Either this is not the correct statement, or the exam has a mistake. It would be true on $[0,R]$.

Comment: Good to know. I never did see exam solutions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For $n>R\geq x>0$, $$\frac{nx^2}{n^3+x^3}\leq \frac{x^2}{n^2}\leq \frac{R^2}{n^2}$$

and a similar bound can be found when $x<0$, by the fact that $-R\leq x$.

which gives you uniform convergence on any interval $[-R,R]\backslash (-\mathbb{N})$. As you rigthfully point out, $x$ cannot be a negative integer. Notice that uniform convergence essentially only cares about how the tail of the series behaves and not on a *fixed* (i.e. not depending on $x$) number of finite terms , in this case $R$ of them.

Comment: Thank you Alex I appreciate it